# Passing python objects to R functions in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook with Python 2 and want to use rpy2 to plot a heatmap.

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import Formula, Environment
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector, FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
import warnings


a = np.array([1.5,2.3])
b = np.array([4.2,5.1])
c = np.array([[0.3, 0.6],[0.6, 0.3]])

r.image.plot(a,b,c)
```

gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'SignatureTranslatedFunction' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

How do I properly pass the parameters into this function? Specs: rpy2 2.5.6 with R3.3.3 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because `image.plot` apparently comes from the package `fields`. Using `image` from base R's `graphics` library, do e.g. this:

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from IPython.display import Image, display
from rpy2.robjects.lib import grdevices

rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
grf = importr('graphics')

a = np.array([1.5,2.3])
b = np.array([4.2,5.1])
c = np.array([[0.3, 0.6],[0.6, 0.3]])

with grdevices.render_to_bytesio(grdevices.png, width=1024, height=896, res=150) as img:
    grf.image(a, b, c)
display(Image(data=img.getvalue(), format='png', embed=True))
```

gives [image]

To use `image.plot`, you'd have to run

```
fields = importr('fields')
```

and replace `grf.image(a, b, c)` with `fields.image.plot(a, b, c)`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't run "from rpy2.robjects.lib import grdevices" though, it says "ImportError: cannot import name grdevices." However, I can run 'grdevices = importr('grDevices')" but it doesn't have the "render_to_bytesio" function you used. I am using rpy2 2.5.6 with R3.3.3 and Python 2.7

Comment: In fact it's telling me that "rpy2.robjects.lib" can only be completed with "grid" -- I'm not sure what grid even is

Comment: what exactly does the message say? `grid` is an R-package!

Comment: The message says "ImportError: cannot import name grdevices."

Comment: But I definitely have more R packages (like fields!)

Comment: I would say try updating `rpy2` first, because `grdevices` definitely exists in the newer versions

Comment: I had to do a couple hacks (which I will post as an answer in a few hours or so) but long story short I got it working. I also needed to change 'fields.image.plot' to 'fields.image_plot'.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Last questions, 1) how do I get rid of the structure(c(1.5, 2.3), .Dim=2L) stuff, 2) how do I save this image locally and display at the same time?

Comment: I am not certain of how to save it at the same time - but if you can add `grdevices.png(filename="name.png")
grf.image(a, b, c)
grdevices.dev_off()` somewhere, then you will also have a saved plot. As for the structure, it shouldn't be there if you use `fields` package. But when using base R `image`, `grf.image(a, b, c, xlab = "a", ylab = "b")` will change the axes labels